# Insert multiple values into SQL Server column from C# Winforms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a table for translators, and each translator is capable of translating from one source language to many target languages. I am creating a Windows form application for such a table, and have tried using a listbox for such an entry, but it gives me the following error

> The variable name '@lang_code' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Code:

```
List<String> SelectedItems=new List<String>();

foreach (System.Data.DataRowView s in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{           
    string select = s.ToString();
    SelectedItems.Add(select);
    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang_code", select);
}
```

Comment: Where do you execute `myCmd`? Inside or outside the `foreach` loop?

Comment: This is a horrible design - **do NOT** put multiple values into a single database cell ! This is against even the **first normalization** rule of database design!

Comment: @ekad outside the foreach loop

Comment: Aside from the horrible database design you should take a look at this article about using AddWithValue. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Let's say there are two items selected, `abc` and `def`. You only have one parameter (`@lang_code`), what is your expected value of `@lang_code`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a parameter named "@lang_code" multiple times to the same query.  This isn't legal in any SQL language I'm aware of.  This would be the equivalent of declaring multiple c# variables with the same name in the same scope.

It sounds to me like you actually want 3 separate tables with relationships between them.

A table of Languages, a table with Translators, and a table containing the languages that each Translator knows.  The Languages table is just a list of all the languages that your application is aware of.  The Translator table should have a private key, with one row per translator.  The LanguagesKnown table should have one row per translator per language known, with a foreign key pointing to the primary key of the translator and the primary key of the language.

You will end up with a very shallow tree structure that a relational database can easily handle.  It will look something like this:

**Language**

1. LanguageId
2. DisplayName

**Translator**

1. TranslatorId (pk)
2. Name

**LanguageKnown**

1. LanguageKnownId
2. TranslatorId
3. LanguageId

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error, looks like you have added the @lang_code parameter to myCmd (SqlCommand) and have not cleared that parameter collection. So the SqlCommand already has a parameter called @lang_code. You could create multiple commands within one SqlConnection, or clear the parameters collection prior to re-adding @lang_code

Comment: Or add the parameter outside the loop and change its value inside it before executint the command